# How to call multiple JavaScript functions by using function in onclick event and using loop to count functions from array in function?

Tags: javascript

How to call multiple JavaScript functions  by using function in onclick event and using loop to count functions from array in function?
Demonstration:

```
var arr = [function one(){console.log("one")}, function two(){console.log("two")} ];

htmlElement.onclick = function(){
  for(var i = 0, a = arr.length; i < a; i++ ){
  }
}
```

Comment: arr[i](); //add this in the loop

Comment: It worked without me pushing the html element, I tried arr[i].call() it worked the same

Comment: if you must do that, use `arr[i].apply(this, arguments)` so that the functions get called with the same context and arguments as any normal `onclick` handler.

Comment: Didn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - don't use `onclick` - it's brittle (especially when used inline within HTML) and harks back to how JS was written in the '90s.

Use `addEventListener` instead:

```
arr.forEach(function(callback) {
    htmlElement.addEventListener('click', callback);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0,a = arr.length; i<a; i++){
    arr[i]();
}
```

This should work.